# Could the current page not be affected when submitting a form from it?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to submit a form inside a page, but don't want the page to do any refresh. I just want to submit some data to the server. How can I make it?

Comment: This is essentially the purpose of AJAX and its ilk. jQuery has a nice set of tools for it, including a form serializer.

Comment: Yes i will agree with kojiro.. you can achieve this using AJAX with the help of Jquery framework.

Comment: @kojiro, Thanks. It great to know AJAX actually supports this. I could dive into Ajax APIs. In the time being, could you show me a simple example to submit a form and just ignore its result (not to refresh the page)?

Comment: @Thomson: There are a _million_ examples of AJAX form submission on the world wide web. Do a basic web search.

Comment: Did anyone say *iframes*? ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use AJAX for this. Cross-browser support for AJAX is a pain, and I'm not willing to demo it without a framework, but here's a [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) example:

```
$("#myform").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post(
        url,
        $(this).serialize(),
        function () { /* What to do when the data is successfully posted */ }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use an ajax [`post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) to submit (POST/GET) the data to a page where the server uses this data. Also add [`e.preventDefault();`](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_preventdefault.asp) to stop refreshing the page from the forms `action`

Comment: I am newbie to Ajax, so a concrete code example with a simple form will be great appreciated.